# Why does Visual Studio 2012 Change VB6 .Cls files?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, vb6

As soon as I open a .cls file in Visual Studio 2012 many parts of the code are automatically changed.

For example:

```
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
```

becomes

```
objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
```

And

```
objHTTP.open "POST", strURL, False
```

becomes

```
objHTTP.open("POST", strURL, False)
```

When I go to build these changes break the build, and I only noticed the changes when viewing the current version of code with the previous. I'm not an expert with VB6 and these changes weren't obvious!

Comment: Why would you open VB6 files in a VB.NET IDE in the first place? They are different languages.

Comment: It converted from VB6 to VB.NET syntax.  Maybe you ought to use a different text editor :)

Comment: The main reason for using Visual Studio is that I often have C# files open and I use TFS etc. Sometimes i'll be checking in C# code alongside VB6 as a single changeset, but if there's no way of switching it off i'll use notepad++ for VB6 :)

Answer (score 4):

VB6 and VB.Net are very different animals.

The changes you see are because the syntax has also changed in a big way. It is not possible to open a VB6 project in Visual Studio 2012 and run it. Moving an application to VB.Net is a major task, sometimes meaning a rewrite is required.

For more, see:
[What are the differences between VB.NET and previous versions of VB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363509/what-are-the-differences-between-vb-net-and-previous-versions-of-vb)

Comment: +1 with a quibble. Moving a VB6 application to VB.Net does not always mean that a rewrite is required. There are third-party migration tools that can ease the pain. See [some of the other questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb6-migration?sort=votes&pagesize=50)

Comment: @MarkJ: Feel free to edit my answer with a better terminology.